# Split a list on an index in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a split predicate with 4 parameters. The first parameter (Index) is the index at which the complete list should be split. The second parameter (CompleteList) is the list that the predicate should split on a given index. Parameter 3 and 4 are output parameters (here FirstHalf and SecondHalf).

```
split(_,[],[],[]).
split(0,CompleteList,FirstHalfList,CompleteList).
split(Index,[CompleteListHead|CompleteListTail],FirstHalfList,SecondHalfList) :-
    append(FirstHalfList,[CompleteListHead],NewFirstHalfList),
    NewIndex is Index-1,
    split(NewIndex,CompleteListTail,NewFirstHalfList,SecondHalfList).
```

An example of the desired output of a query would be

```
split(2,[5,4,3,2,1],X,Y).
X=[5,4],
Y=[3,2,1]
```

I understand how the second half of the list can be returned, yet I have trouble returning the first half. The current output of the program for the example query is

```
split(2,[5,4,3,2,1],X,Y).
X=[],
Y=[3,2,1]
```

Is it possible to return the FirstHalfList (instead of the NewFirstHalfList, which backtracks to an empty list) or is the current code a wrong approach towards writing Prolog predicates ?

Edit: thank you all for the responses, they have given me a better insight.

Comment: You should **not** ignore the warnings the compiler gives. What's the purpose of the second clause (i.e. `split(0,CompleteList,FirstHalfList,CompleteList).`) ? Prolog data model is **relational**, meaning you should estabilish **relations** among predicates' arguments...

Comment: The second clause determines when the split predicate knows it is ready. Once index reaches zero, it knows that the SecondHalfList equals the remainders of the CompleteList. But indeed, the FirstHalfList is pretty useless here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split predicate recursively reduces its second argument.
The first clause handles the terminal case (when Index > length of given list)
The second clause handles the other terminal case when Index is reduced to 0.

```
split(_,[],[],[]).
split(0,L,[],L).
split(Index,[CompleteListHead|CompleteListTail],[CompleteListHead|FirstHalfTail],SecondHalfList) :-
    Index >= 0,
    NewIndex is Index-1,
    split(NewIndex,CompleteListTail,FirstHalfTail,SecondHalfList).

?- split(2,[5,4,3,2,1],X,Y).
X = [5, 4],
Y = [3, 2, 1] ;

?- split(8,[5,4,3,2,1],X,Y).
X = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
Y = [] ;

?- split(4,[5,4,3,2,1],X,Y).
X = [5, 4, 3, 2],
Y = [1] ;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the condition in the third clause be `Index > 0`, i.e. use strict inequality?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this.

Here is a compressed way:

```erlang
split(Index,List,Left,Right) :-
   length(Left,Index),       % Actually CREATES a list of fresh variables if "Left" is unbound
   append(Left,Right,List).  % Demand that Left + Right = List.
```

Then:

```
?- split(2,[5,4,3,2,1],X,Y).
X = [5, 4],
Y = [3, 2, 1].

?- split(2,[],X,Y).
false.

?- split(0,[],X,Y).
X = Y, Y = [].
```

It can even automagically work "in reverse":

```
?- split(L,[5,4,3,2,1],[5,4],Y).
L = 2,
Y = [3, 2, 1].
```

Think about why this works!

**Debug printout helps here:**

```erlang
split(Index,List,Left,Right) :-
   debugme(Index,List,Left,Right),
   length(Left,Index),
   debugme(Index,List,Left,Right),   
   append(Left,Right,List),
   debugme(Index,List,Left,Right).
   
debugme(Index,List,Left,Right) :-
   format("Index: ~q, List: ~q, Left: ~q, Right: ~q\n",[Index,List,Left,Right]).
```

Then:

```
?- split(L,[5,4,3,2,1],[5,4],Y).
Index: _6640, List: [5,4,3,2,1], Left: [5,4], Right: _6646
Index: 2, List: [5,4,3,2,1], Left: [5,4], Right: _6646
Index: 2, List: [5,4,3,2,1], Left: [5,4], Right: [3,2,1]
L = 2,
Y = [3, 2, 1].
```

Notice the way in which the set of variables appearing in the clause get progressively filled with information.

Answer (score 1):

```
%! split(?INDEX0,?Xs0,?Ys,?Zs)
%
% `Xs0` is split at `INDEX0` into `Ys` and `Zs` .

split(_,[],[],[]) .

split(INDEX,Xs0,Ys,Zs)
:-
lists:length(Ys,INDEX) ,
lists:append(Ys,Zs,Xs0)
.
```

```
/*
?- split(2,[5,4,3,2,1],Ys,Zs) .
Ys = [5,4] ,
Zs = [3,2,1] .
*/
```

```
/*
?- split(INDEX,Xs0,[5,4],[3,2,1]) .
INDEX = 2 ,
Xs0 = [5,4,3,2,1] .
*/
```

```
/*
?- split(INDEX,Xs0,Ys,Zs) .
Xs0 = Ys = Zs = [] ? ;
INDEX = 0 ,
Xs0 = Zs ,
Ys = [] ? ;
INDEX = 1 ,
Xs0 = [A|Zs] ,
Ys = [A] ? ;
INDEX = 2 ,
Xs0 = [A,B|Zs] ,
Ys = [A,B] ? ;
INDEX = 3 ,
Xs0 = [A,B,C|Zs] ,
Ys = [A,B,C] ? ;
INDEX = 4 ,
Xs0 = [A,B,C,D|Zs] ,
Ys = [A,B,C,D] ? %etcetera.
*/
```